# onClick add/remove class inside loop is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I'm working on flexslider here onClick next I want to add class it is working but randomly click is coming when I first click class added then on second click not coming third click coming so on. I want to add a class every click. Here might be the problem in if()

```js
$('.flex-next').on('click', function() {

  if ($('.timeline span').hasClass('clicked')) {
    $('.timeline span.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  } else {
    $('.timeline span').removeClass('clicked');
    $('.timeline span').addClass('clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.timeline {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.52);
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
}

.timeline span:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  animation: yourAnimation 1s 0s linear;
}

.timeline span.clicked {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  animation: yourAnimation 1s 0s linear;
}

@keyframes yourAnimation {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  82% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-next">Click here</div>
<span class="timeline">
   <span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Is there only 1 span inside timeline or there could be many?

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio  Nothing in the span same code I have added.

Comment: I think its better to use `toggleClass()`, remove this line `$('.timeline span').removeClass('clicked');` inside your `else`.

Comment: @Mark Gerryl Mirandilla I tried toggleClass also same result $('.timeline span').toggleClass('clicked');

Comment: Will you provide a picture of your html? The one currently running in your browser. I'm speculating that there are many spans in 1 timeline

Comment: @JerdineSabio I have updated my question check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive the required functionality as

```
$('.flex-next').on('click', function(){    
   if (! ($('.timeline span').hasClass('clicked')) ) {
        $('.timeline span').addClass('clicked');
        setTimeOut(function(){
  $('.timeline span').removeClass('clicked');
   } , 200)
    }
});
```

Comment: same result and `!` should be come inside if();

Comment: you can check now , there were some mistakes in the previous one

Answer (score 0):

To add/remove a class on click, it is better to use jquery toggleClass function.

Moreover you may need to execute the click event after the document is loaded correctly

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.flex-next').on('click', function(){   
    $('.timeline span').toggleClass( "clicked" );
  });
});
```

For more info, you may refer to: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: i have already tried toggle but not working properly same output

Comment: @Husna How about executing the code after the document is ready. I modified the code too.

Comment: yeah i wrote inside  document.

Comment: @Husna according to the code in your post the code is not executed inside document ready function: $( document ).ready(function() { }); as I did above